# Cross-site and SPFieldLookup

Tags: lookup-column, cross-site

I've read a numbered time that SPFieldLookup is cross-site by its nature. But now I'm a little bit confused, here is my SharePoint structure:

- /SiteCollection

  - /Site1

    - Projects
  - /Site2

    - Customers

Does cross-site mean that I can do a lookup field for `Customers` and access it within my `Projects`form?

And if it is possible, how should I do it? I've looked into those articles but it seem to be for a site and his subsites only:

http://developing-dummy.blogspot.fr/2012/02/sharepoint-and-cross-site-lookup-fields.html

http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/tag/spfieldlookup/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're able to create a Lookup column from another site.
You can use the script bellow in PowerShell. It'll create a Customer lookup column in your Project list.
Before running the script you'll need to update the url and list names with yours.

```
#Get the webs and lists
$web1 = Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/site1/
$web2 = Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/site2/
$projectList = $web1.Lists.item("Projects")
$customerList = $web2.Lists.item("Customers")

#Add a lookup field
$projectList.fields.AddLookup("Customer", $customerList.id, "false")

#Get the created lookup field
$LookupField = $projectList.Fields["Customer"]

#Set the lookup web ID and lookup field
$LookupField.LookupWebId = $customerList.ParentWeb.ID
$LookupField.LookupField = $customerList.Fields["Title"].InternalName
$LookupField.Update();
```

Comment: Please do not only link to answers, add an abstract of the information on the link (off course with a link to the source) :)

Comment: @Robert, After reading your comment I figured out that I was wrong with my answer. Now it's updated. Thanks ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the GUI?

Comment: No, there is no solution via GUI! Thank you very much, carobauque!

Answer (score 0):

Via UI it is not possible to create a site-cross lookup column. Taking a look on the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.addlookup.aspx) there is the method [AddLookup(String, Guid, Guid, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430950.aspx) where it is possible to specify also a web.

Example:

```
Add-PSSnapin *SharePoint*

$urlWeb1 = "http://sitecollection/site1/"
$guidList1 = "ProjectsGuid"

$urlWeb2 = "http://sitecollection/site2/"
$guidList2 = "CustomersGuid"

$isFieldRequired = $false #Or $true, depending on your needs

$web1 = get-spweb $urlWeb1
$list1 = $web1.Lists[[Guid]$guidList1]

$web2 = get-spweb $urlWeb2
$list2 = $web2.Lists[[Guid]$guidList2]

$list1.fields.AddLookup("NameOfTheNewColumn", $list2.ID, $web2.ID, $isFieldRequired )
```

Please use Guids!