# SharePoint2013 Cross site lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

I have a parent site, created a list and added few items to it. then I have created a site column type lookup referred to that list.
then created a sub site, created a new list and added the site column to it. Now, when I create an item in the sub site list, the lookup works fine as expected, but when I click on the lookup item, I get a pop up message saying something went wrong.
“List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user” 
I have observed that in URL appending subsite name. but it should not.

Expected result should be open the parent site list item.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but not using the UI.
Example copied from [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/79647/7045):

```
#Get the webs and lists
$web1 = Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/site1/
$web2 = Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/site2/
$projectList = $web1.Lists.item("Projects")
$customerList = $web2.Lists.item("Customers")

#Add a lookup field
$projectList.fields.AddLookup("Customer", $customerList.id, "false")

#Get the created lookup field
$LookupField = $projectList.Fields["Customer"]

#Set the lookup web ID and lookup field
$LookupField.LookupWebId = $customerList.ParentWeb.ID
$LookupField.LookupField = $customerList.Fields["Title"].InternalName
$LookupField.Update();
```